# array of pointers fortran

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran

Again, array of pointers in Fortran. So well, I've a derived type:

```
type :: t_context_pointer  
    type(t_context),pointer :: p_ctx  
end type t_context_pointer
```

When I do in the main program:

```
type(t_context_pointer),allocatable :: tab_ctx_ptr(:)  
type(t_context),allocatable,target :: ctx  
allocate(tab_ctx_ptr(1))  
allocate(ctx)  
tab_ctx_ptr(1)%p_ctx=>ctx
```

it works. But when I use a function call:

```
type(t_context_pointer),allocatable,target :: tab_ctx_ptr(:)
allocate(tab_ctx_ptr(n))
call alloc_ctx(tab_ctx_ptr,n,1)
```

with elsewhere:

```
subroutine alloc_ctx(tab_ctx_ptr,n,i)
    integer,intent(in) :: n,i
    type(t_context_pointer),intent(inout) :: tab_ctx_ptr(n)

    type(t_context),allocatable,target :: ctx

    allocate(ctx)
    tab_ctx_ptr(i)%p_ctx=>ctx
end subroutine
```

it seg_fault later in the code. Is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ctx` is in the scope of the subroutine `alloc_ctx` and gets deallocated as soon as you leave the subroutine. Accessing it later (by means of the pointer) will cause a segfault.

In the first example, you allocate `ctx` in the main program, so its scope will be until the end of the program.

Why don't you `allocate` `tab_ctx_ptr(i)%p_ctx` directly:

```
subroutine alloc_ctx(tab_ctx_ptr,n,i)
    integer,intent(in) :: n,i
    type(t_context_pointer),intent(inout) :: tab_ctx_ptr(n)

    allocate(tab_ctx_ptr(i)%p_ctx)
end subroutine
```

As for deallocation: You could use something like this to deallocate all pointers (but not the array itself):

```
subroutine dealloc_ctx(tab_ctx_ptr,n)
    integer,intent(in) :: n
    type(t_context_pointer),intent(inout) :: tab_ctx_ptr(n)
    integer            :: i

    do i=1,n
      ! Check whether the current element has an allocated element and 
      ! deallocate if necessary. 
      if ( associated(tab_ctx_ptr(i)%p_ctx) ) deallocate(tab_ctx_ptr(i)%p_ctx)
    enddo ! i
end subroutine
```

Comment: Why doing that, I mean not directly? In fact it is a first step of a more complex code which plans to manage multi-threads allocations and to assure locality of data in the different memories (e.g. NUMA).

Comment: And finally, if there is an automatic deallocation: how to do as in a C code?

Comment: I edited my answer to show an example... BTW: It is *always* a good idea to check the `stat` of the allocation!

Comment: Now, I'm confused... What C code? Your example is in Fortran?!

Comment: Of course I check, I've just simplified the exemple. BTW: your solution works, so first, thanks, second, I'me sure I've read an example with an allocation like my example in a forum...

Comment: "As in a C code" means: if you allocate an array in a function and use a pointer on the allocated data, when you quit the scope of the function, you don't lost the array. Wrong?

Comment: No. You can pass an allocatable to a subroutine and allocate it there. It will stay allocated. **But:** *local* `allocatable` variables in the subroutine will get deallocated at the and of the subroutine (unless they have the `save` attribute, but don't try that at home ;-)).