# Fortran : array of pointers

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran

Here, there is an example of [array of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400047/array-of-pointers-fortran).

But there seem to be no other way than using a structure containing a pointer... For example in C, it can be done [without structures](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_array_of_pointers.htm):

```
const int MAX = 3;
int *p[MAX];
```

In Fortran, how to code an array of pointers?

Comment: Hi, thanks! Should I delete the question?

Comment: No, you do not have to. It can stay as it is.